# SQL: how to know if a field has "Allow nulls" checked or not checked by SQL command

Tags: sql, null

I want to know which table's field are required or not required so I have to get "Allow nulls" state. How to do that?

Comment: What database engine are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Access, etc....

Comment: Thanks, I'he just found.
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'myTable'

Answer (score 11):

I will assume you are talking about SQL Server.

There is a table, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, that contains meta-data about the columns in the database.

You can do this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
```

IS_NULLABLE gives you the "Allow Nulls" value used in the designer.

Answer (score 1):

If your in MySQL use the sql command

```
DESCRIBE Table;
```

Where table is the name of the table you want to examine

Answer (score 1):

Try this (SQL Server)

```
select sysobjects.name, syscolumns.name, syscolumns.isnullable
from   sysobjects join syscolumns
   on  sysobjects.id    = syscolumns.id
  and  sysobjects.xtype = 'U'
  and  sysobjects.name  = 'your table name'
```

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, you should stop using "sysobjects" and start using the proper and more focused catalog views in the "sys" schema, e.g. "sys.tables", "sys.columns" and so forth